# Fix giant viewcontroller with lots of states

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` in my application that contains a `UITableView`. This tableView has a few different states for section 2. The rows in this section can vary by height, cell type and number of cells.

The way I used to handle this was one `UIViewController` with lots of different if-statements in the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`. Now, after a while, this has given me quite a lengthy and complicated controller.

I thought about two possible routes to fix this. The first one would be different `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` classes, based on an if-statement. The other would be to load in a different `UITableViewController` for each of the possible states.

What do you guys think would be the cleanest solution? Or are there any other cleaner solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create an extension for viewcontroller which confirms to tableView dataSource and delegate protocols.

To achieve this we can create a custom method in presenter class to handle all this code and call this method whenever required.